# MySQL RDS Database Connection

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I just created a test RDS instance through the AWS console, and it has been created successfully (it says it is running and available). I currently have my security groups configured to SSH port 22 (MyIP) Custom TCP Rule port 3307 (myIP) and HTTPS port 443 (MyIP). I am currently trying to connect through MySQL workbench. I am using the endpoint of "RDS_URL" :3307 and inputting my username and password. Every time I try to connect, I get this error:

> Can't connect to MySQL server "-RDS_URL-" (10060)

Any suggestions?

Comment: any reason you are you using 3307 instead of 3306?

Comment: wasn't working on 3306, figured orgnization's firewall might have been blocking it, so I just tried it on 3307, but it doesn't work on either.

Comment: I believe 3307 is the default replication port. I would change it back to 3306 and have another look the settings for your security group. Also why have 22 and 443 open? What are you doing on that uses those ports on a RDS instance?

Answer (score 0):

Default MySQL port is 3306, In RDS you can't change it but in datacenter hosted DB, you can change by changing in my.cnf file and restart it. Before doing it open the port from firewall rules.